# Finding the product of the slopes of 2 unknown lines tangent to a circle with known intersection point outside circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, tangent-line

Given, two lines are tangent to the circle, and they intersect at a point $(0,14)$ not on the circle, find the product of the slopes $m_1*m_2$
$$l_{1}: y = m_{1}x + c_{1}$$
$$l_{2}: y = m_{2}x + c_{2}$$
$$Circle: y^2 + x^2 = 49$$

I find the derivative of slope from the circle equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -x$$
For $x_{1}$ is a point that lies on the circle
$$m_{1} = f'(x_{1}) $$

I create a point-slope equation using the point (0,14)
$$y-14=(x+0)m_{1}$$
sub $m_{1} = -x$
$$y=-x^2+14$$

So here's where I'm not too sure I'm correct about.
I try to find $x_{1}$ that lies on the circle by subbing $y = \sqrt{x^2+14}$ derived from the circle equation.
$$\sqrt{x^2+14} = -x^2+14$$
$$0=x^4-29x^2+182$$
solve for x
$$x=\frac{29+\sqrt{113}}{2} or \frac{29-\sqrt{113}}{2}$$
However, $x > radius$ for both results, which is not possible since it needs to lie on the circle. How do I proceed?

Answer sheet states m1*m2=-3

Comment: $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$ and not $-x$.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the mistake, managed to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of any tangent at $(7\cos t,7\sin t)$

$$x\cos t+y\sin t-7=0\iff y=7\csc t-x\cot t$$

So,  the gradient is $=-\cot t$

If it passes through $(0,14)$

$$14\sin t=7\iff\sin t=\dfrac12\implies \cot t=\pm\sqrt{\csc^2t-1}=\pm\sqrt3$$

So, the product of the gradients $=(-\sqrt3)(\sqrt3)=?$